# Rest | @Produces and @Consumes : why dont they both get called for same MIME-type

Tags: java, rest, jersey

a newbie in JAX-REST (jersey 1.8 impl)

I have a class for Resource "/hello"

```
package com.lbs.rest;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("/hello")
public class Test {


    //-- produces MIME type text/plain
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public  String thankYouTxt(){
        System.out.println("thankYouTxt");

        return "thankYouTxt\n";
    }

    //-- consumes MIME type text/plain
    @GET
    @Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String thankYouInputTxt(){
        System.out.println("thankYouInputTxt");
        return "thankYouInputTxt";

    }


    //-- produces MIME type text/html
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public  String thankYouHTML(){
        System.out.println("thankYouHTML"); 
        return "thankYouTxtHTML";
    }


    //-- consumes MIME type text/html
    @GET
    @Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
    public  void thankYouInputHTML(){
        System.out.println("thankYouInputHTML");
        //return "thankYouInputHTML";
    }



    //-- produces MIME type text/xml 
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    public  String thankYouXML(){
        System.out.println("thankYouXml");
        return "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?> <message>thankYouTxt</message>";
    }
    //-- consumes MIME type text/xml    
    @GET
    @Consumes(MediaType.TEXT_XML)
    public String thankYouInputXML(){
        System.out.println("thankYouInputXML");
        return "thankYouInputXML";
    }



}
```

when I sent a request with a header `Content-Type : text/html`, I would expect both the `@Produces` and `@Consumes` annotated methods `thankYouHTML()` and `thankYouInputHTML()` to be called.

but only the `@Produces thankYouHTML()` method get called? why? why is not the `@Consumes` annotated method `thankYouHInputTML()` also called?

Comment: A GET request cannot consume anything!

Comment: you are right.. but which HTTP methods are "consumer" only ? and which are "producers" only ? and whoch could play both roles ?

Comment: There are no HTTP methods (that I know of at least) which can do both. Methods which consume as for instance `POST` and `PUT`. There are others as well.

Comment: `POST` can use both `Consumes` and `Produces` annotations. In fact I would say it's pretty rare to use `POST` with only `Consumes`, because 9 out of 10 cases you want to return the updated entity or some other info in your response. Jax-RS looks at request path and method to make a match. If multiple methods match it just picks the first one. You can use this to have a very specific match first and then a wider match second for those cases where the first one did not match.

Answer (score 7):

You should remember that:

1. Only one method is executed for a single request. So it is impossible to execute two methods (or more) in single request;
2. JAX-RS runtime decides which one method should be executed according to request header values sent to to the server.

`JAX-RS` runtime tries to match:

- http method (`GET`,`POST`, ...) with proper annotation (`@GET`, `@POST`,...);
- request path (`'/api/something'`) with the proper `@Path` annotation;
- http `content-type` header ([link](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html)) with proper `@Consumes` annotation;
- http `accept` header with propper `@Produces` annotation;

So (for example) `@Produces` annotation does not denote that annotated method produces something. It denotes that method will be executed when matching `accept header` will be contained in request.

If You need more information abou RestFull webservices i advice You to read these resources:

- [rfc2616](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596158057.do)
- [RESTful Java with JAX-RS - By Bill Burke](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1847196462)