# How to get request body of POST request using REST API in java

Tags: java, rest, httprequest, httpresponse

I am using  javax.ws.rs.* classes for REST API.
HttpConnection Class and URLConnection for connection.

I have one method As

```
@POST
    @Path("/{containerId}/{caseDefId}/customcasestart")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response claimTasks(@Context HttpHeaders headers, @PathParam("containerId") String containerId,
            @PathParam("caseDefId") String caseDefId,String payload) {}
{
    logger.info("Payload : "+payload)

}
```

This payload is not fetching data from request body .

I am passing data from postman-Body-Raw as Follow :

```
{
 "userId":"123",
 "date":"2020/07/15"
}
```

But it gives null. And I have no idea how to fetch body parameter using any method or class?
Anyone please help here.

Comment: Have you tried adding `@ResponseBody` before `String payload` ? Something like `@ResponseBody String payload`

Comment: Thanks For Prompt Reaply .@ResponseBody is from Spring framework , i am not using Spring, Yet i tried but  give error as Requestbody is disallowed for this location

Comment: Then you can add in the parameters `HttpServletRequest request`, remove `String payload` and inside the method do the following `String payload = IOUtils.toString(request.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);` Keep in mind `IOUtils.toString()` belong to apache commons library. In case you want to go with old good plain java, you can work the input stream given by the request object.

Comment: I tried using your above suggestion but it gives me error like : com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: Cannot construct instance of`javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest` (no Creators, like default construct, exist): abstract types either need to bemapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or contain additional type informationat [Source: (io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletInputStreamImpl); line: 1


But also i tried with @RequestBody payload , that gives me request body , So what you suggest should i use requestbody from springframework or not ?

Comment: I cannot tell entirely why that issue is thrown without seeing further implementation of the code. Regarding Spring, if you are up to use Spring in your application, go for it but I wouldn't use it if you are only going to use it in this specific part. Have you also tried adding `@Context` to `HttpServletRequest request`?

Comment: Aren't the `@Produces` and `@Consumes` annotations conflicting with each other? And something else: will the `logger.info("Payload : "+payload)` line be even reachable, seeing as you do `{}` before that?

Comment: @NeoChiri , yes i tried using HttpServletRequest ,it was giving error ,@Context i used for httpheader but how can i use with payload that i dont know

Comment: @Fullslack.dev This is my typing mistake , you can ignored {} once.Produces and Consumes works fine in my code

Comment: Did you add it like this `@Context HttpServletRequest request`?

Comment: If your code is working fine, I'm not sure what you are asking this question for then. Sorry for the sarcasm, but what I normally do is to reduce a method so you have less things that can break it. Does it work with only `@Consumes` and nothing else than the `String payload` argument in place? If yes, expand from that. If no, something else is breaking the code (something we might not see because it's only a snippet posted here).

Comment: Also check your headers that are send. The way you have your code written at this time is expecting a `http accept header`, as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/17168100/13211030